# Remove event listener not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to remove an event listener with Javascript, but it seems not working.

I need to pass the object `event` in the handler so this is why I'm using `.bind()`.

**My code :**

```
if (sidebar) {
  listItems.forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.showSubmenu = showSubmenu;
    listItem.addEventListener('click', listItem.showSubmenu.bind(this, subLists), true);
  });

  if (sidebarButton) {
    sidebarButton.addEventListener('click', onClickOnButton.bind(this, sidebar));
  }
}

if (sidebar.getAttribute('data-reduce') === 'true') {
  listItems.forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.removeEventListener('click', listItem.showSubmenu, true);
  });
}

function showSubmenu(subLists, e) {
  var target = e.currentTarget,
      subList = target.querySelector('.sidebar__sublist');

  if (subList) {

    if (subList.style.display !== 'block') {

      [...subLists].forEach(hideSubList);

      $(subList).slideDown('slow', function() {
        subList.style.display = 'block';
        target.querySelector('.sidebar__list__item__link__arrow').textContent = 'keyboard_arrow_up';
      });

    } else {
      $(subList).slideUp('slow', function() {
        subList.style.display = 'none';
        target.querySelector('.sidebar__list__item__link__arrow').textContent = 'keyboard_arrow_down';
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Result :** The event is not removed.

Comment: `listItem.showSubmenu` is **not** the same as `listItem.showSubmenu.bind(this, subLists)`. When you `bind` a new object is created to handle.

Comment: Needing to remove an event listener is a code smell in my book

Comment: @GACy20 Yes but I need to passe the object `event`, so is there any other solution ?

Comment: @tonymx227 you already have jQuery. why not use `.on()` and `.off()` ?

Comment: I'm in process to remove my jQuery library, in the next few months I want to use native javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @GACy20 said listItem.showSubmenu is not the same as listItem.showSubmenu.bind(this, subLists)

try doing it like this

```
listItem.showSubmenu = showSubmenu.bind(this, subLists);
listItem.addEventListener('click', listItem.showSubmenu, true);
```